# Best way to write a mobile web site?

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I want to create a mobile application and from a tutorial I have been looking at, a single page is loaded and subsequent content is inserted into the first page via Ajax calls. In addition, the back button keeps track of the page history.

I know that I am not doing page loads by using Ajax and was wondering if this should be the way to create the application or should I just do simple page requests and not use Ajax which may not look to great on a mobile application?

Also in the future I would like to use PhoneGap and was wondering if the Ajax version would work?

TIA
JD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)? Takes care of most of the things you should be concerned with out-of-the-box. Alternatively, there is [jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/) you can also use.

Comment: Hi Brad, from the tutorial they were crafting a solution without the frameworks which got me thinking about whether in general Ajax is the way to go rather than normal page loads.

Comment: @JD: You might also check out the "mobile-html5-boilerplate" on github: https://github.com/shichuan/mobile-html5-boilerplate

Answer (score 2):

[Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) is another option for the UI.

**EDIT:** I've looked at a few and found this to look the most professional (in terms of smoothness of animations) on my Android 2.2 phone.

Comment: Just browsed around this site, I like it. I also like that they have "actual solutions" being demoed, good fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a mobile application using PhoneGap or Titanium, it is better to use Ajax because the pages will load faster and you are sure that the end handset, on which  your application is installed, will support Ajax.

OTOH, if you are developing a mobile website, it might be better to go for a normal page loads. You may also apply progressive enhancement to use Ajax, if your user's client supports it.